# What is proper way to persist time or date -type of information into database?

Tags: java, postgresql, date, time, persist

What is the proper way to save date or time based data in the database?
What are the proper "field mappings" for java to postgresql(or to some other database)?

That data should be stored in utc format without timezones.

-> timestamp and date based stuff fails in here, those will add current timezone (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

-> what are the other options?

should I use "plain epoch/integer" column and other column for timezone? But then I cannot use all the functions etc. that the database is providing for me.

I could use hibernate with some jodatime magic, but in my current stack I don't have hibernate in use.

Possible solutions:

1). Change the computer/java timezone -> java will in the UCT (eg. export TZ="GMT" or -Duser.timezone=UCT)

2). Use epoch/Integer/Long values in date/time fields / types -> works but now I cannot use build in database functions.

3). Use Jodatime with custom hibernate datatypes?

4). Use Java8 new time and date apis?

Comment: A Date in java does not have a timezone. It only has a timezone once you format it as a String (or convert to java.util.Calendar). Date is just a thin wrapper around a long (milliseconds since epoch, January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).

Comment: If you save/persist the Date into database it will convert to time+timezone

Comment: Postgres *does* support `timestamp without time zone`. Did you try that? I think in that case no transformation will happen when you read that into a `java.sql.Timestamp` (but I'm not entirely sure)

Comment: this is a java problem, there is nothing wrong in the databases :)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, it is best to use the Postgres data type [**`timestamptz`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) (short for `timestamp with time zone`) when dealing with multiple time zones or when you want to save all timestamps as UTC.

Don't let the name mislead you, the *time zone* is not actually saved. But (as opposed to `timestamp [without time zone]`) the time zone from textual input is taken into account as modifier to compute the actual **UTC** timestamp value, which is saved.
On *output*, the text representation of the value is formatted according to your *current time zone setting*: timestamp is shifted and the according time zone modifier attached to it.

Note that timestamps without appended time zone are interpreted according to the current time zone setting of your session. If you want to enter a *literal UTC value disregarding the current time zone*, it has to be:

```
'2014-08-21 16:39:09+0'::timestamptz
```

not:

```
'2014-08-21 16:39:09'::timestamptz  -- would assume current time zone
```

Detailed explanation in this related answer:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it would be best to store dates as UTC on the database. In oracle you can use a DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype. You can then use the java layer to present your dates in local time to the user and with a java.sql.timestamp column. Joda is essentially built in to the latest version of java so definitely use that for any conversions etc. The alternative would be to store timestamp with timezone in oracle and perhaps use oracle date functions in your sql and stored procedures to convert the date as required. We do the former, but it may depend on your team (db people vs java people) and your audience - are there likely to be lots of different timezones in the user base or is timing on the DST changeover going to break your app.

If you can describe particular situations you are concerned about I'm sure someone will help out. Storing your data in UTC will at least ensure that your data is solid but may require many conversions in the presentation layer.

Comment: but is it not the same in oracle case that if you are using eg. timestamp in the moment of the persist it will automatically add the timezone offset..

Comment: pasuna - please compare TIMESTAMP with TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE, timestamp would normally contain UTC value returned by the server unsing something like SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm

Comment: I am talking about the java class, not the database field type: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Comment: That's correct but if your underlying data structure doesn't store the timezone separately you may have a lot of trouble presenting it across multiple zones easily

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single correct way but I my opinion is that you should store time as a long unix timestamp and single dates as epoch days. Java 8 has nice functions to deal with them. Avoid locking yourself with jodatime and hibernate just to manage a date.

What do you mean functions that the database is providing you?
You can always do SQL selects with integers and long since they are called from your program.

If you need a lot of manual use of the database (not programmatic) then you may want to use human readable dates.

Comment: yes there is nice functions etc. in java 8 but how about earlier versions of java? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: If you want to be able to work with any db server you'll have to use long as I have with android and sqlite. If you want to use some of the functionality of the db timestamp with timezone will do a lot of work for you. We currently use joda as a library from Java 7